# simple bash script to check if tunnel exists [catching stdout and stderr]

Tags: linux, bash, interface

i'm trying to write a simple bash script for a cronjob to check if some interfaces (tunnels) exsisting. if not i'd like to start another script that (re)starts them. my problem is: i don't get the "IF" working:

```
#!bin/bash

for i in tun1 tun2 tun3 tun3 tun4 tun5
  do OUT="$(ip a show $i up)";

    if [[ $OUT == *"does not exist."* ]]; then
      echo "$i is down"
    else
      echo "$i is up"    
    fi

done
```

current output is:

> ./check_tunnel.sh
>
> tun1 is up
>
> tun2 is up
>
> tun3 is up
>
> tun3 is up
>
> tun4 is up
>
> Device "tun5" does not exist.
>
> tun5 is up

Comment: Tun1-4 are really up, so this part is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Device "tun5" does not exist.` is printed to stderr (standard error).
Your script catches only stdout (standard output).

You may redirect stderr to stdout to fix the problem (trailing `2>&1`).

```
OUT="$(ip a show $i up 2>&1)"
```